# How to hide a table in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<table id ="Table2 " border ="1px" style ="height :200px ; width :690px; visibility :hidden; " runat ="server"  >
```

my Table id is "Table2"

```
protected void Button3_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
   Table2.visible=True;
   int Student_id = 0;
   string strqry = "select * from StudentApplication where Student_id='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
   DataTable dt = mc.selectQryDataTable2(strqry);
   DataView dv = new DataView(dt);        
   TextBox15.Text = (string)dv[0]["Group"];
   TextBox16.Text = (string)dv[0]["Enter_Kyu"];
   TextBox17.Text = (string)dv[0]["Enter_Student_Name"];
   TextBox18.Text = (string)dv[0]["Select_Franchise"];
   TextBox19.Text = (string)dv[0]["Select_Sensei"];
   string strqry1 = "select * from competitionmaster";
   DataTable dt1 = mc.selectQryDataTable3(strqry1);
   DataView dv1 = new DataView(dt1);
   TextBox5.Text = (string)dv1[0]["competitiondate"];
   TextBox12.Text = (string)dv1[0]["competitionaddress"];
   TextBox13.Text = (string)dv1[0]["competitionname"];        
   if (Student_id > 0)
   {
      Student_id = Student_id + 1;
   }
   else
   {
      Student_id = 1;
      TextBox14.Text = Student_id.ToString();
   }
}
```

when i click a button3 am getting an error like Table2 is found nu friends plz help me friends.

Comment: You have been here long enough, and asked enough questions to learn how the editor works. Use the code button on the editor (101010) for code samples.

Comment: sorry friends am getting the error like table2 is not found nu so wt to do for that.

Comment: If you are getting an error, you should _copy and paste_ it into your question.

Comment: give us the error.  Is your table wrapped inside another object that requires you to "FindControl"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `id ="Table2 "` with `id ="Table2"`....

There seems to be a space which causes the problem...

Answer (score 4):

Heya, put the table inside a panel control. Access the panel from code behind and set its visibility to false. You have to postback the page or use an update panel to see the effect on your page.

```
Panel1.Visible=False;
UpdatePanel1.Update();
```